# How to get a message from web3.shh using Python

Tags: python, web3.py, message, status-im

Good afternoon. I'm trying to implement the "Status" at the moment. I use the library Web3.shh. I sent the message and gives the answer "True", but I can not receive all the messages on the other address. In the documentation of the Ethereum and in the documentation "Status" I did not find any answers. Tell me how to correctly pull messages from the Geth at? Here's the code:

```
from web3 import shh
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3

status_host = 'https://host:port''
privatekey = '0x....7f2afa922ffdbeac65867f544a....'

connect = Web3(HTTPProvider(status_host))
print('connect status ===> ', connect.isConnected())

ms = shh.Shh(connect)
print('info ===>>>> ', ms.info)

id = ms.addPrivateKey(key=privatekey)
print('id ===>>>> ', id)

user_address = ms.getPublicKey(id)
print('user_address ===>>> ', user_address)

privkey = ms.getPrivateKey(id)
print("privkey => ", privkey)

topic = Web3.toHex(b'AS')
print("topic => ", topic)
text = 'test message'
address_to = '0x0487be55c072702a0e4da72158a7432281e8c26aca9501cd0bfeea726dc85f2611e96884e8fc4807c95c04c04af3387b83350a27cc18b96c37543e0f9a41ae47b5'

mes_send = ms.post(
    {
        'ttl': 20,
        'payload': Web3.toHex(text=text),
        'pubKey': address_to,
        'topic': topic,
        'powTarget': 2.5,
        'powTime': 2,
    }
)

if mes_send == True:
    print('Status message => Send')
else:
    print('Message not send')
```

Comment: I found a solution. In the official documentation 'WEB3.PY -> SHH' everything is described well, except for the indication that the filter should be started in a parallel process. Those. it is necessary to send and receive the file into two files + run the file in an infinite loop with a certain frequency of listening on the filter. The code itself will tell all for itself))

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. In the official documentation 'WEB3.PY -> SHH' everything is described well, except for the indication that the filter should be started in a parallel process. Those. it is necessary to send and receive the file into two files + run the file in an infinite loop with a certain frequency of listening on the filter. The code itself will tell all for itself))

```
from web3 import shh
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3
status_host = 'http://****:9090'
privatekey = '0x5eea64de8906369612593480b7f2a...'
connect = Web3(HTTPProvider(status_host))
print('connect status ===> ', connect.isConnected())
sh_con = shh.Shh(connect)
print('info ===>>>> ', sh_con.info)
id = sh_con.addPrivateKey(key=privatekey)
print('id ===>>>> ', id)
user_pubkey = sh_con.getPublicKey(id)
print('user_pubkey ===>>> ', user_pubkey)
topic = Web3.toHex(b'ESSC')
print("topic => ", topic)
text = b'First test'
sumkey = sh_con.addSymKey(privatekey)
print('sumkey ====>>>> ', sumkey)
address_to = '0x043c03b3b0a0cd00...'
mes_send = sh_con.post(
    {
        'ttl': 40,
        'powTarget': 11,
        'powTime': 5,
        'payload': Web3.toHex(text),
        'topic': topic,
        'pubKey': address_to,
        'sig': user_pubkey,
    }
)
if mes_send:
    print('Message Send')
else:
    print('Message not send')
```

file filter -> :

```
class Daemon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.private_key = '0x36...'
       host = 'http://****:9090'
        self.new_id = '13b994193505744d...'
        self.connection = shh.Shh(Web3(HTTPProvider(host)))

    def ms_filter(self):
        message_filter = self.connection.newMessageFilter({'privateKeyID': self.new_id})
        return message_filter

    def in_daemon(self):
        filter_id = self._create_message_filter().filter_id
        while True:
            messages = self.connection.getMessages(filter_id)

            if messages != []:
                message = messages[0]
                mes_pars = message['payload']
                mes_from = message['recipientPublicKey']
                topic = message['topic']
                timestamp = message['timestamp']
                print('from user => {}'.format(Web3.toHex(mes_from)))
                print('message => {}'.format(Web3.toText(mes_pars)))
                print('topic => {}'.format(Web3.toText(topic)))
                print('timestamp => {}'.format(timestamp))

            time.sleep(0.3)

threads = []
daemon = Thread(target=Daemon().in_daemon())
threads.append(daemon)
daemon.start()
```

Comment: This is not a full solution, it's just a hint. Examples are in the official documentation WEB3.PY -> SHH