# How to send 1-N signalling or broadcast messages on Whisper?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

[From Whisper wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper):

> Low-latency, 1-1 or 1-N signalling messages.

[Shh.post(self, message:)](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.shh.html#web3.shh.Shh.post) and [Whisper Usage / shh.post](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage#post)

> Creates a whisper message and injects it into the network for
>   distribution.

**Example usage of `web3.shh.post`, for more details please see this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/51856/4575):**

```
web3.shh.post({
  pubKey: 'PUBLIC_KEY_OF_THE_RECEIVER',
  ttl: 3600,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

---

When I remove `pubKey` from `web3.shh.post` as arguments; it says: `Error: specify either a symmetric or an asymmetric key`.

> `shh.post({ "topic": t, "payload": p });` No signature, no encryption: Anonymous broadcast; a bit like an anonymous subject-filtered twitter feed.

**[Q]** Since `web3.shh.post()`requires us to provide single public key of the receiver; is it possible to send 1-N or broadcast message using `whisper protocol`? If yes, how?

Comment: I wrote the implementation on python3 [here it is](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/how-to-get-a-message-from-web3-shh-using-python)

Comment: Your answer does not sent 1-N messages. @Sergey Zaharov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommended to use this documentation : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper

[Whisper usage](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage)

**your posted links are  outdated and  moreover are for Whisper v 2.0**

Answer:  It's possible 1:N message if you provide identical symKey for all recipients.

P.S.  My posted links are for Whisper  5.0 , current version of Whisper is 6.0 but  but the API for v6 is almost identical to v5 anyway.

---

**On node-1's geth-client:**

```
generatedSymKey=shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello");    
symKey=shh.getSymKey(generatedSymKey)    
symKeyID=shh.addSymKey(symKey) //ex: "d5212e736703afbb21246e8acd192e4345ea910398544d765ed6b49f0ec524b5"
filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {symKeyID:symKeyID, topic: '0x07678231'}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

**On node-2's geth-client:**

```
generatedSymKey=shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello")    
symKey=shh.getSymKey(generatedSymKey)    
symKeyID=shh.addSymKey(symKey) //ex: "c4c4cecf6ad9499c2386b8ce6416f44684e042e491726b38315646c0b4afadc6"
filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {symKeyID:symKeyID, topic: '0x07678231'}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

---

Than, sending message on another node and both messages show up on **node-1** and **node-2** even if `symKeyID` is either **node-1**'s or **node-2**'s on `shh.post()` function.

Following code is run on `node-1's geth-client`:

**node-1's `symKeyID` is given:**

```
web3.shh.post({
  symKeyID: 'd5212e736703afbb21246e8acd192e4345ea910398544d765ed6b49f0ec524b5', //symKeyID of the node-1
  ttl: 10,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

OR

---

Following code is run on `node-2's geth-client`:

**node-2's `symKeyID` is given:**

```
web3.shh.post({
  symKeyID: 'c4c4cecf6ad9499c2386b8ce6416f44684e042e491726b38315646c0b4afadc6', //symKeyID of the node-2
  ttl: 10,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated links. But how could recipients have identical `symKey` or `publicKey` since they are unique for each recipient? @Baracuda

Comment: I have  just pushed working ssh demo:  https://github.com/achiko/whisper-v6-test  I used shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword('....' ) method with one password.

Comment: I am pretty sure each receipt should have a unique `symKey`. What do you get `symKey` with following: `shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello")` which I get : `a0ce4c9103be09614d59103ca5aeee0bda8e59e9f6112f6c0b40f439ab0b4ab9` for receipt-1 and for another receipt I get different one. `4a6c15f288bfa9949702aa9a5e5bd305b6f48681513a266e8a3c42e58433f859` .

Comment: **generateSymKeyFromPassword**
Generates the key from password, stores it, and returns its id.  
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage#generatesymkeyfrompassword
Its just ID stored locally.

Comment: This is not my solution omg ...  this method generateSymKeyFromPassword is from official documentation and  I would like to say that  the official API  is wrong ?  or  Go ethereum client works wrongly ?

Comment: This is not possible: "if you provide identical symKey for all recipients". Each recipient has a unique symKey since each has different private key.

Comment: Please run this code and test  :  do not  downvote before it please ....  https://gist.github.com/achiko/b4b58bb1bde29ab40a3782a0d9bc5c01

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79925/discussion-between-baracuda-and-alper).

Comment: SymkeyID its  just only id  returned  when you  generating symKey.   you  can get get symKey by using symkeyID   ...  so symkeyId is different for  different nodes but symKey is identical for  one password string.

Comment: you  can run code code in  different nodes and you  will get identical symKey.

Comment: I have just tested  in  2  different nodes,  which comment ?

Comment: 1. if you run shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello") it will return different symKeyId on every run. 
2. but if you run shh.getSymKey(<symkey returned from generateSymKeyFromPassword>) you will always get identical symkey for identical password on every node.

Comment: I got your point, I added your answer with a tutorial code. @Baracuda

Answer (score 3):

### Solution using `Web3.py`:

I have followed following [ssh-mode code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/tests/core/shh-module/test_shh_filter.py).

---

`receiver.py` that runs on node-1:

```
from os.path import expanduser
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3
import asyncio
import time


def handle_event(event):
    print(f"recipientPublicKey={event['recipientPublicKey'].hex()}")
    print(event["payload"].decode("utf-8"))


async def log_loop(filter_id, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in w3.geth.shh.getMessages(filter_id):  # event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)  # TODO: add try catch
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
    home = expanduser("~")
    topic = "0x07678231"

    print("Initializing...")
    key_id = w3.geth.shh.newKeyPair()  # generates a new public and private key pair for message decryption and encryption.
    public_key = w3.geth.shh.getPublicKey(key_id)
    filter_id = w3.geth.shh.new_message_filter({"topic": topic, "privateKeyID": key_id, "recipientPublicKey": public_key})
    print(f"my_public_key={public_key}")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(log_loop(filter_id, 2)))
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Output:

```
my_public_key=0x0429824f14966d802e8a12b09c276361cdf13eda4dd5f4f776d0a2a4db61ba4e24683be84df2b521ff8c6290e3851bf9b59a8e9a7e13345fee603de9be862f5ef3
```

---

After `Node_1`'s messages are sent; I have copied printed `receiverPublicKey` into `receiver_pub` variable on the following code. I run following code on `Node 2`. `Node 2` sends a message to the network. Later I press enter on the `Node_1` and `Node_1` prints the message

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

# obtained from node_1 and assigned here.
receiver_pub =
"0x0429824f14966d802e8a12b09c276361cdf13eda4dd5f4f776d0a2a4db61ba4e24683be84df2b521ff8c6290e3851bf9b59a8e9a7e13345fee603de9be862f5ef3"

topic = '0x07678231'
payloads = [web3.toHex(text="test message :)"), web3.toHex(text="2nd test message")]

web3.geth.shh.post(
    {"powTarget": 2.5, "powTime": 2, "ttl": 60, "payload": payloads[0], "topic": topic, "pubKey": receiver_pub}
)
```