# Whisper: How to send a message from one node to another that is located on different host?

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper, message

- geth version: 1.8.15-unstable
- Python: 3.5
- OS: osx/linux

---

I have followed this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52932/4575).

On the answer's approach, I observe that each node can only send message to itself and other nodes don't filter/see those messages. For example, when `node-1` sends a message to the network; it won't show up on the `node-2` such that node-2's `web3.shh.info{memory}` remains 0, where I assume that it never catches the message.

---

I have tried using `Web3.js` and `Web3.py` where sent message on `Node_1` does not show up on `Node_2`.

#### => This is as far as I came by using `Web3.js`:

The way I start `geth`:

```
geth --syncmode fast --cache=1024 --shh --datadir $DATADIR/private  --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --networkid 12345 --rpcapi admin,eth,net,web3,debug,personal,shh
```

**On node-1's geth-client:**

```
generatedSymKey=shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello");    
symKey=shh.getSymKey(generatedSymKey)    
symKeyID=shh.addSymKey(symKey) //ex: "d5212e736703afbb21246e8acd192e4345ea910398544d765ed6b49f0ec524b5"
filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {symKeyID: symKeyID, topic: '0x07678231'}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

**On node-2's geth-client:**

```
generatedSymKey=shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello")    
symKey=shh.getSymKey(generatedSymKey)    
symKeyID=shh.addSymKey(symKey) //ex: "c4c4cecf6ad9499c2386b8ce6416f44684e042e491726b38315646c0b4afadc6"
filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {symKeyID: symKeyID, topic: '0x07678231'}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

---

Then, **node-1** sends message to the network, where only `node-1` receives it but `node-2` does not.

Following code is run on `node-1's geth-client`:

**node-1's `symKeyID` is given:**

```
web3.shh.post({
  symKeyID: 'd5212e736703afbb21246e8acd192e4345ea910398544d765ed6b49f0ec524b5', //symKeyID of the node-1
  ttl: 10,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

---

#### => This is as far as I came by using `Web3.py`:

`Node_1` runs `shh_filter.get_new_entries()`
 in order to catch messages but `len(received_messages)` returns 0, where there is no message is received and `web3.shh.info{memory}` remains 0.

**On node-1:**

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")

import time, sys;

from hexbytes import (
    HexBytes,
)

receiver = web3.shh.newKeyPair()
receiver_pub = web3.shh.getPublicKey(receiver)
print('receiverPubK: ' + receiver_pub);

topic = '0x07678231'

shh_filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter({
    'privateKeyID': receiver,
    'topics': [topic]
})

input("Press Enter to continue...");

received_messages = [];
received_messages = shh_filter.get_new_entries()
print(len(received_messages)) # Returns '0'
print(web3.shh.info.memory) # Returns '0'
```

Output:

```
receiverPubK: 0x04226d96bf9857ac0ba429c1e8b480a2811ce47cb526dbd3829d7586e5cae740198ba291f3eca0f279f82db8a136be90ea9ec629ed6cd1d45cc7f873159811757d
Press Enter to continue...
```

---

After `Node_1`'s messages are sent; I have copied printed `receiverPublicKey` into `receiver_pub` variable on the following code. I run following code on `Node 2`. `Node 2` sends a message to the network. Later I press enter on the `Node_1` and any of those messages does not show up on the`Node_1`:

**On node-2:**

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
from web3.shh import Shh
Shh.attach(web3, "shh")

import time, sys;

from hexbytes import (
    HexBytes,
)

receiver_pub='0x04226d96bf9857ac0ba429c1e8b480a2811ce47cb526dbd3829d7586e5cae740198ba291f3eca0f279f82db8a136be90ea9ec629ed6cd1'; # obtained from node_1 and assigned here.

topic = '0x07678231'
payloads = [web3.toHex(text="test message :)"), web3.toHex(text="2nd test message")]

web3.shh.post({
        'powTarget': 2.5,
        'powTime': 2,
        'ttl': 60,
        'payload': payloads[0],
        'topic': topic,
        'pubKey': receiver_pub
})
time.sleep(1)

web3.shh.post({
        'powTarget': 2.5,
        'powTime': 2,
        'ttl': 60,
        'payload': payloads[1],
        'topic': topic,
        'pubKey': receiver_pub
})
```

**[Q]** How could I send a whisper message from one node to another? What do I do wrong on my approaches?

---

**On the reciever `shh.info.memory` remains 0 when sender node posts a message.**

Please note that, I have opened issue on `Web3.py` and `go-ethereum` but no one responded. I have also tried one node is one of those nodes was bootnode and the other one needs to have its enode address in --bootnodes, which also did not work.

- Opened [Web3.py issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1031).
- Opened [go-ethereum issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17545).
- Opened [Whisper issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17545#issue-355065821)

Comment: I follow this repo https://github.com/achiko/whisper-v6-test and it working fine, but we have to gen sym key from the same password `shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("password")`

When I'm using difference pwd then node-2 cannot receive msg from node-1

Comment: I am using same password as well, but not sure why it is not working on my code. Did you tried on different nodes? Could you also share the code you tried, I can try it as well.

Comment: I run on two nodes with difference port on the same host

https://github.com/hadv/whisper-v6-demo

Comment: That's why it works because they are on the same host. On my case, I run on two different node on completely different host, which was not working. I will try your code and see will it work or not.

Comment: you can try with `ws://localhost:8545` instead of `http://localhost:8545`

Comment: According to web3.js, i found that they also document that we should use ws, not http

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-shh.html#web3-shh

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. I am doing like that as well: `Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545" ));`

Comment: if you using like that you need to set provider for shh later

`
// change provider
web3.setProvider('ws://localhost:8546');
`

Comment: btw, can you put your full `geth` cmd to the question for everyone can know with which options your node was started.

Comment: Sure I updated my question with my full `geth` command.

Comment: you should add more options like `--ws --wsaddr "0.0.0.0" --wsapi "eth,net,web3,admin,shh" --wsorigins "*" --wsport 8546` to allow connecting by websocket

Comment: I will try first without `--ws --wsaddr "0.0.0.0" --wsapi "eth,net,web3,admin,shh" --wsorigins "*" ` than with that and see does it make a difference. On the code you shared I did not see any `--wsport 8546` ? Also I think using `--wsaddr "127.0.0.1"` should be more safe.

Comment: my code is using ws with port 8546 `const web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');`

Comment: `subscriber.js` does not returns the posted message. And I am pretty sure this (https://github.com/achiko/whisper-v6-test) will not work on different host that try to send message to each other.

Comment: Did you try ws in different hosts?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work on the same host as well. We have to use `messageFilter` instead of `subscribe`.

Comment: I want to make sure that you start sshpost after subscribing

Comment: I am running as follows: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/1d23cbd942e13fa15a164c544e385ec6

Comment: your code didnot work even in the same host, but if I change to `const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8546"));` then it worked properly; so I think we must use `websocket`, not `http`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82870/discussion-between-alper-and-ha-dang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no node in the network started as `bootnode`. But I have manually added static nodes using `admin.addPeer()`.

There are three main nodes, their `enode` is shared publicly where any new coming peers connected to all those three using `admin.addPeer("mX_enode")`. `mX` stands for either `m1` or `m2` or `m3`. Also all those 3 nodes are connected to each other using `admin.addPeer("mX_enode")` as well. I have added few nodes which connects to all those 3 nodes, that makes network more stable.

All those three nodes in the network uses following `geth` line, and newly connected nodes uses same line without `--nodiscover` flag:

```
geth --syncmode fast --cache=1024 --shh --datadir $DATADIR/private --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="*" --networkid 12345 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal,shh --nodiscover
```

Please see the image where all nodes are connected to each other.

[image]

Later I pick a sender and receiver node, where both `admin.peers` returns other node's `enode` so I verify that selected sender and receiver node is connected to each other on the network.

**=>** Receiver and sender node runs following code on its `geth` console:

```
generatedSymKey=shh.generateSymKeyFromPassword("hello");    
symKey=shh.getSymKey(generatedSymKey)    
symKeyID=shh.addSymKey(symKey)
filter = web3.shh.newMessageFilter(
        {symKeyID: symKeyID, topic: '0x07678231'}, 
        function(err, res) {console.log(web3.toUtf8(res.payload))});
```

I have stored sender and receiver's `symKeyID` where I will use it to post message. Sender's returned `symKeyID` is `321f3531fad3de1dd8344da26cba1a074ee3689acb796ecb8e5bdf8507b1a0ef`. Receiver's returned `symKeyID` is `ed30b966e40cec9088fb6054c1823d3ff36941aaa002ebd2eea9d5a6efd1a9fe`:

**=>** Than sender node copy paste its `symKeyID` into following code piece to post its message

```
web3.shh.post({
  symKeyID: '321f3531fad3de1dd8344da26cba1a074ee3689acb796ecb8e5bdf8507b1a0ef', //symKeyID of the sender
  ttl: 10,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

**=>** Receiver also do the same. Receiver copy paste its `symKeyID` into same code piece to post its message.

```
web3.shh.post({
  symKeyID: 'ed30b966e40cec9088fb6054c1823d3ff36941aaa002ebd2eea9d5a6efd1a9fe', //symKeyID of the receiver
  ttl: 10,
  topic: '0x07678231',
  powTarget: 2.01,
  powTime: 2,
  payload: web3.fromAscii("Hello there!")
  });
```

And I can see the sent message on the sender and receiver node's `geth` console.

---

**I observe that:**

In order to user Whisper protocol, where are not required to use any `bootnode`. Later I have tried running receiver and sender node without `--nodiscover` and still they were able to send and receive messages between each other.